# How to control animation fraction in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

When animating a View between 2 states, how it can be achieved to animate not just from state1 to state2 or back, but set specific animation fraction like it's done with UIViewPropertyAnimator's fractionComplete in UIKit?

Here is the code where I can animate between 2 states on tap. But I need to **follow slider value** (or get **value from socket**, or **scrollView offset**, whatever is CGFloat from 0 to 1). Basically, need to pass an animation fraction so the view will represent it's state on the timeline statically. In short, need to **SET the animation progress**.

```
struct TransitionView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = false
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch isExpanded {
            case true:
                VStack {
                    Circle()
                        .strokeBorder(Color.green, lineWidth: 5)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "circle", in: namespace)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    Text(verbatim: "I am Circle")
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "text", in: namespace)
                }
            case false:
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .strokeBorder(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "circle", in: namespace)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    Text(verbatim: "I am Circle")
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "text", in: namespace)
                }
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: isExpanded)
        .onTapGesture {
            isExpanded.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to *set* the animation progress, or are you trying to *get* it?

Comment: I am trying to set it.

Comment: I don’t think you can with this setup. You can’t have a neutral Bool or a half a Bool. Pre iOS 17 I use GeometryEffect to control animations, I saw something in the WWDC videos about keyframing but haven’t had time to dive into it there is likely a better way now.

Comment: I understand I can't have a half Bool. That's why I've mentioned UIViewPropertyAnimator as an example. It is not making a half of Bool, it can present a half of animation between true and false using fractionComplete which is CGFloat from 0 to 1.